# Intellij indentation format - method definition with/without braces (in scala)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, auto-indent

I am having a minor annoyance with intellij indentation which I hope someone can help me with.

If I write a method declaration with braces, indenting works properly:

```
def function(a:A): B = {  //  When I hit return on this line...
    //  the cursor goes here (4 spaces in)
}
```

However, if I don't include braces, I don't get any indentation:

```
def function(a:A): B = // When I hit return on this line...
//  the cursor goes here (0 spaces in)
```

To make matters stranger, if I already have some code on the first line before hitting return, I *do* get the correct spacing

Before:

```
def function(a:A): B = some.code.here  //cursor is immediately after the = sign
```

After:

```
def function(a:A): B =
    some.code.here   // Correct indentation behavior.
```

So what I want to know is this: is there a setting which will result in an auto-indent if I hit return at the end of a method declaration without any code behind the cursor?

Thanks!

Comment: Go to file > settings > editor > code style to customize it

Comment: @Zar Which specific setting would one need to change there in order to change this behavior?

Comment: @sepp2k Sorry, but I don't know, I haven't used Scala. I'm not certain if this setting exists, but if it does that is where it would be. I didn't post an answer because I didn't actually check for this specific setting.

Comment: did you ever find out how to fix this?